# Data Structure for fast insertion and random access in already sorted data

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, data-structures, tree

```
p = random_point(a,b)
#random_point() returns a tuple/named-tuple (x,y)
#0<x<a 0<y<b
if centers.validates(p):
    centers.insert(p)
#centers is the data structure to store points
```

In the `centers` data structure all `x` and `y` coordinates are stored in two separate sorted(ascending) lists, one for `x` and other for `y`. Each node in `x` points to the corresponding `y`, and vice versa, so that they can be separately sorted and still hold the pair property: `centers.get_x_of(y)` and `centers.get_y_of(x)`

[image]

Properties that I require in data structure:

1. Fast Insertion, in already sorted data (preferably log n)
2. Random access
3. Sort x and y separately, without losing pair property

Initially I thought of using simple `Lists`, and using `Binary search` to get the index for inserting any new element. But I found, that, it can be improved using self balancing trees like AVL or B-trees. I could make two trees each for `x` and `y`, with each node having an additional pointer that could point from x-tree node to y-tree node.

But I don't know how to build random access functionality in these trees. The function `centers.validate()` tries to insert `x` & `y`, and runs some checks with the neighboring elements, which requires random access:

```
def validate(p):
    indices = get_index(p)
    #returns a named tuple of indices to insert x and y, Eg: (3,7)
    condition1 =  func(x_list[indices.x-1], p.x) and func(x_list[indices.x+1], p.x)
    condition2 =  func(y_list[indices.y-1], p.y) and func(y_list[indices.y+1], p.y)
    #func is some mathematical condition on neighboring elements of x and y
    return condition1 and condition2
```

In the above function I need to access neighboring elements of `x` & `y`
 data structure. I think implementing this in trees would complicate it. Are there any combination of data structure that can achieve this? I am writing this in Python(if that can help)

Comment: I think two indexable skip lists, one for 'x's and one for 'y's can do it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list

Comment: Define "fast". Is O(log n) fast enough for random access? If so, then the indexable skip list mentioned above is a good idea. What about insertion? What's "fast"?

Comment: Can you use two different dictionaries with corresponding key/value pairs? Insertion is O(1). Random access is O(1). How frequently do you need to sort elements? Is sorting upon insertion the critical aspect of this data structure?

Answer (score 1):

Class with 2 dicts that hold the values with the keys being the key of the other dict that contains the related value to the value in this dict.  It would need to maintain a list per dict for the current order to call elements of that dict in when calling it (your current sort of that dicts values).  You would need a binary or other efficient sort to operate on each dict for insertion, though it would really be using the order list for that dict to find each midpoint key and then checking against value from that key.